# favicon not showing up in any way

Tags: html, favicon

I have in my index.html, between my `<head>` tags the following line of code:

```
{% block head %}
  <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href='static/img/favicon.ico'/>
{% endblock %}
```

This is not working somehow. But if I go to: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/img/favicon.ico' The favicon shows up. So this means that the favicon works, it's displayable but I can't find a way to put it next to the URL as it should be. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you have given and the URL provided it looks like it is a flask app.

If it is flask you need to load the static files as follows, which will help you to load the favicon as well.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favicon.ico') }}">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="static/img/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking questions about Django?